# Dynamic list-view population - on custom ajax calls in jquery mobile , Handling Back button queries

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am having a jquery Mobile page . 
It has a deep list which has got Category at the parent level, on click it fetches the sub categories and populates them to the list. Now the thing is that in this i have to handle back buttons . I could take care of this using Ben Alman's BBQ but then everything is to be handled on hash change event manually. But in jquery mobile it already uses bbq internally as per i have read.

**Is there any easy way i could push the current page state into    history and    it will be handled by jquery mobile when a user clicks    a back button    ?**

The reason to avoid it is that that it saves many bugs . I have used it before and when the things get too deep , handling back buttons gets very difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you do not empty the list or remove the page from DOM programatically on the `pagehide` event; you should be getting back to previous page's list using `<a href="#" data-rel="back"></a>` for your back buttons.

Comment: But the thing is that i am not gonna change the hash... how it handle that ??

Comment: Could you explain why you want to avoid the hash change?

Comment: bhai, actually there were things which i had faced in my prev project . Wherein there were many parameters which had the drills on ajax. It was more of a single page app . So everything had to be in ajax. And BBQ was the thing which had me running around.